# Regular expression to select semicolon those are present outside of single or double quote

Tags: java, regex, split

I am using **java and regular expression** to split sql queries on the basis of **semicolon(;).** But sometimes a update statement may contain multiples queries as column value. So i want to split only the main sql queries not the queries present inside it as column value or sub query. For that i am selecting only those semicolons that are **present outside of quotes.**
Currently i am using the regular expression:

`String[] queries=content.split("\\s*;\\s*(?=([^']*+'[^']*+')*+[^']*$)])`;

**but works only when single quote is present**. Sometimes it happens that sub queries may be surrounded by double quotes. so i want to skip those too.
for example:

```
update table set column='select * from table_"name;";' ;
```

or

```
update table set column="select * from table_'name;';" ;
```

i want to select only the outermost semicolon, outside of any **nested quotes**

so what i did to add double quote condition is

```
String[] queries=content.split("\\s*;\\s*(?=([^']*+'[^']*+')*+[^']*$)(?=([^\"]*+\"[^\"]*+\")*+[^\"]*$)");
```

added another look ahead similar to single quote. But its not working. Any way to make the **regex work for both single quote and double quote?**
Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: For the general case here you would need a _parser_ to handle this.  This is what your database actually uses when processing a SQL statement.

Comment: can you explain a bit about parser and how to use it?